# Adjective phrase

Tags: grammar

In the example sentence 
"All norms, including/alongwith/together with our moral ones,were violated"
Does the prepositional phrase"including/alongwith/together with our moral ones" function as adjective phrase modifying "norms"?if not,  then what function is the phrase performing? 
Thanks

Comment: It can't be a PP and a AdjP at the same time, and no it's not a modifier. "Including" is very similar to a coordinator in that it can link phrases, as it does in your example. In fact, one leading grammar claims that this use provides some evidence for suggesting that "including", "along with" and "as well as" have a use where they are reanalysed as marginal  members of the coordinator category, thus functioning as markers. "Our moral ones" would then be an NP within the second coordinate.

Comment: Thanks Bill, Can coupled with and together with  also be called coordinating conjunction? Regards